# Cannot zoom in live view in Darktable?

Tags: 18.04, darktable

Using darktable 2.6.0 from PPA on Ubuntu 18.04. I just connected a Canon S3 IS to it, it can be found and connected to from darktable. I get a Live View in darktable, however, the camera only supports PTP mode, it does not support the Live View protocol (saw in https://www.linux.com/learn/how-remote-control-your-camera-darktable-linux that it is relevant), probably because of that, I cannot zoom in the live view:

[image: darktable]

Note that zoom tool is disabled, and the rendered view is really small.

Now, I get it if the program simply tries to show all the pixels it's possible to retrieve from the camera; and if the zoom tool button is actually intended to control the zoom of the camera. But in principle, it should be possible to implement a software zoom, or rather scale of however small an image, possibly with some smoothing, just to make it take up a greater proportion of the GUI window space.

So I was thinking - is it possible to have a zoom in that sense (as in, simply increase the viewer size) in darktable, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think darktable can control the zoom operation in your camera. I think darktable doesn't have to do that anyway.

I haven't tested the tethering function in darktable, so I'm just interested in your question. Here is my guess.

Try Alt+1, Alt+2, Alt+3. These shortcuts are for zooming in the Lighttable and Darkroom mode in darktable gui application.